# how to exclude a .js file for a particular page

Tags: php, javascript, html, dynamic

my js files are included through header. i dont want to have some .js files included in certain pages, while that particular page is loading. is it is possible.??? help me please.....

Comment: You want to include them after the page has finished loading? Just put them just before the </body> tag. Want to include them after the page has loaded? You'll need to use a .js file to include them on window.onload.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
    if (! some_condition() ) {
?>
<script …></script>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What specifically is the page?  Can you just re-write the header on the one page?  Or, if you use a header function, just rewrite the function like:

```
<?php
echo "<html>";
echo "<head>";
if (use a regexp to extract the page URL ) {
    echo "<script>  ....   </script>
    }
echo "</head>";
.........
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array of files to include.

In your main file:

```
$jsFiles=array('jquery.js','mylib.js','test.js');
```

In your header file:

```
foreach($jsFiles as $jsFile){
    print("<script type='text/javascript' src='$jsFile'></script>");
}
```

Code is not tested but that should give you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == 'page.php'){ 
?>

<script></script> 
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please have a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update your answer to provide more detail. Specifically, it would be helpful if you explained how this solves the problem